# Hookup hard search key to SearchView

Tags: android, android-widget, android-searchmanager, google-now

I have an app with a search view in the action bar and I am trying to get the hard search key to activate it in addition to touching the view but everything I have tried has resulting in launching Google Now from my app.

I have tried the following. The commented code was my second attempt to emulate the user touching the search view but it did not work. The search feature works perfectly through the touch screen I am simply having issues getting the hard key to activate it.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch(keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH:
            /*mSearchView.setFocusable(true);
            mSearchView.setIconified(false);
            mSearchView.requestFocus();*/
            onSearchRequested();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

**The action view**

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/menu_search"/>
```

Comment: Can you be more clear , what you want to do on keydown of seach key.

Comment: I would like for it to activate the SearchView action view in my action bar exactly as if the user had touched the view. I have added the menu definition above.